# Test Flight Crash Report

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, testflight

I am keep on getting crash from my application in which i have integrate test flight 8.2 beta. Will You please tell me what does this crash report means. I think this is due to test flight sdk.

```
   0 CoreFoundation 0x37c938bf __exceptionPreprocess + 163
   1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x317791e5 objc_exception_throw + 33
   2 CoreFoundation 0x37c937b9 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
   3 CoreFoundation 0x37c937db +[NSException raise:format:] + 35
   4 CoreFoundation 0x37c00671 -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:] + 161
   5 Foundation 0x31b4971b -[NSMutableDictionary(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 23
   6 AppName 0x0014a1cb -[TFAirTrafficController getSystemLog:] + 731
   7 AppName 0x001486dd -[TFAirTrafficController checkForOldLogs] + 249
   8 AppName 0x00148849 -[TFAirTrafficController checkForOldData:] + 49
   9 Foundation 0x31b39a91 -[NSThread main] + 73
   10 Foundation 0x31bcd5a1 __NSThread__main__ + 1049
   11 libsystem_c.dylib 0x360bbc1d _pthread_start + 321
   12 libsystem_c.dylib 0x360bbad8 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: This is just a stacktrace. Don't you have any more output?

Comment: This is the complete Stack trace that i get from it.

Comment: Try downloading the "0.8.2 BETA 4" version

Comment: how can i get crash file on test flight. And i have follow all steps given in read me file for integration

Comment: Actually i do not know which of the class is throwing this exception. And my application is large and also in app store So i cannot give all application code.

Comment: It is quite impossible for us to help you if we don't know what kind of error this is. Try to find a way to make TestFlight to report more data back to you.

Comment: You don't get a full crash report with all threads and last exception backtraces from TF. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8705553/474794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to insert nil into a dictionary in [TFAirTrafficController getSystemLog:]. Make sure the object is not nil before attempting to insert it. Also make sure your key is not nil as well.

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by Nikolai TFAirTrafficController is test flight's code. So I guess the real solution is to make sure you are on the latest stable TestFlight SDK

Comment: `TFAirTrafficController` is part of the closed source Testflight SDK.